# Largest hyperrectangle contained in an ellipsoid

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, volume

I am looking for a hyperrectangle with maximum volume which is contained in an ellipsoid.
My Ellipsoid is defined as
$\mathcal{E}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid x^T P x \leq c \}$, where $P>0$.

For smaller dimension I can write an optimization problem.
But for $n=23$, the optimizer have to check $2^{23}$ vertices.
Does somebody have a closed form solution?

Edit: I am looking for a hyperrectangle whose edges are parallel to the coordinate axes. And $P$ is not a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 2):

By diagonalizing $P$, your problem is equivalent to maximizing $\prod_{i=1}^n x_i$ subject to $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i x_i = 1$, $x_i \ge 0$ (the corresponding hyperrectangle having vertices $(\pm \sqrt{x_1}, \ldots, \pm \sqrt{x_n})$).
Show (using a Lagrange multiplier if you want) that the optimal solution will have all $c_i x_i$ equal.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. But more precisely I looking for a hyperrectangle which is parallel to the axis for a non-diagonal P. 
Any idea?